# Distance between two points under the complex square root map?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers

Suppose I have two points in $\mathbb{R}^2$,

$$
x = (x_1,x_2) = r_x(\cos\theta_x,\sin\theta_x)\quad\text{ and }\quad y = (y_1, y_2) = r_y(\cos\theta_y,\sin\theta_y),
$$

and the angle coordinate is to lie inside $(-\pi,\pi)$. Consider 'a variant' of the complex square root map defined as

$$ 
\omega(x) = \sqrt{r_x}\left(\cos\frac{\theta_x}{2},\sin\frac{\theta_x}{2}\right).
$$
This maps $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(x,0) \,|\, x\leq 0\}$ onto the half-space with positive $x$ component.

I'm curious what is the general relation between

$$
|x-y|\quad\text{ and }\quad |\omega(x) - \omega(y)|.
$$
Since $\omega$ is a square-root map, the naive intuition tells me that

$$
|\omega(x) - \omega(y)| \sim |x-y|^{1/2},
$$
but a closer look seems to reveal that the situation is more nuanced. For instance, , if we let $r_x = r_y = k$, then a tedious calculation revals that

$\frac{|\omega(x) - \omega(y)|}{|x-y|^{1/2}} =  \frac{|\omega(x) - \omega(y)|^4}{|x-y|^{2}} = \tan\left(\frac{\theta_x - \theta_y}{4}\right)^2$

and the RHS goes all the way from 0 to $+\infty$ for admissible values of the angles. In particular there is no dependence on $k$.

The particular aspect I'm interested in can be summarised as follows. What is the largest $\lambda$ for which there exists $C > 0$ such that

$$
|\omega(x) - \omega(y)| \geq C|x-y|^{\lambda},
$$
for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(x,0) \,|\, x\leq 0\}$. Is it $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$? Can it even be stated in this way?

Many thanks for any potential insight!

Comment: This [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition) may be useful...